# Recyclerview is displaying only single item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've logged no. of items and that gives me 17 but `Recyclerview` only shows 1.
Also like in other solutions I set my root `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.
I've used similar code in other apps too, but here it doesn't work.
Please help. Am I missing anything?

**Here's my single_post_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/main_blog_post"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#fff"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/blog_user_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipse"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.024" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/oxygen_bold"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/blog_user_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Blog Date"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/blog_user_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blog_user_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blog_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blog_user_image"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blog_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotoregular"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_paragraph"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blog_title" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And here's my adapter:**

```
package com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.HelperUtils.BlogPost;
import com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.R;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.BlogViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;



public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){
    this.blog_list = blog_list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.single_blog_list_item,parent,false);
    return new BlogViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
    //String timestamp = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().toString();
    //Log.i("Timestamp",timestamp);
    final BlogPost blogPost = blog_list.get(position);

    String blogImageUrl = blogPost.getImage_url();
    String blogThumbUrl = blogPost.getThumb_url();
    String blogTitle = blogPost.getTitle();
    String blogDesc = blogPost.getDesc();

    Log.i("blog","title : "+blogTitle);
    Log.i("blog","desc : "+blogDesc);
    Log.i("blog","image : "+blogImageUrl);
    Log.i("blog","thumb : "+blogThumbUrl);


    holder.title.setText(blogTitle);
    holder.desc.setText(blogDesc);




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i("BLOG",String.valueOf(blog_list.size()));
    return blog_list.size();
}

public class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private View mView;
    private TextView desc,title,username;
    //private TextView blogDate;
    private ImageView blogImage;
    private CircleImageView userImage;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);
        //blogDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
        blogImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);

    }
}

}
```

**Here's my fragment layout**

```
package com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.Adapters.BlogRecyclerAdapter;
import com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.HelperUtils.BlogPost;
import com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView blogListView;
private List<BlogPost> blog_list;
private BlogRecyclerAdapter blogRecyclerAdapter;

//firebase
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
    blogListView = view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);
    blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);

    blogListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));

    blogListView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            int count = 0;
            for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                    blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}

}
```

Fragment in which I'm displaying recyclerview:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.thenetwork.app.android.thenetwork.Fragments.HomeFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/blog_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Plz post activity layout too... might be problem of visibility...

Comment: Have you checked size of list after `notifyDataSetChanged` into adapter...?

Comment: When I log the size in adapter it gives me correct no. So I think that should not be an issue.

Comment: blogListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); use activity context.

Comment: check the height of RecyclerView, it should be wrap_content.

Comment: Thanks, but still no success.

Comment: post your `fragment_home.xml`.

Comment: Please post here your `fragment_home.xml`, so we can check issue if there in it.

Comment: Updated, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really silly mistake from my side, I was also using a drawer in MainActivity which was overlapping the recyclerview (bad coding by me) because of which I was unable to scroll and it appeared like recyclerview displayed only single item.
Sorry and thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are just notifying the data not adding it to the adapter.
Try doing this

> Inside the Adapter add a method to add all the list data at once.

```
 public void addAllItems(List<BlogPost> items) {
    blog_list.clear();
    blog_list.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> And at the last line of onEvent add the below code

```
 blogRecyclerAdapter.addAllItems(blog_list);
```

and remove the   `blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. What could be the possible problem, Firestore ? I used same code in various other apps. It worked there.

Answer (score 0):

make some change in home fragment when you get data that time define adapter object like below code ...

```
        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

        BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
        blog_list.add(blogPost);

        blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);

        blogListView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
        blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

and remove two line in onCreateView method like below

```
        blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
    blogListView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a new adapter each time data is received? You should add data to list in adapter instead.

Comment: if not create adpater object in every time then make if condition like

Comment: Thanks, but still it shows only one item. Also, I don't think it's adapter problem as when I log no. of items in adapter class, it gives me an exact number.

Comment: if not create adpater object in every time then make one method and call    like  private void setAdapter(){
        if (blogRecyclerAdapter==null)
        {
            if (!blog_list.isEmpty()) {
                blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);

                blogListView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);

                blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }  and call this method method getting data.

Comment: check in bloglist array item size.